# Laravel Sail & platform selection

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail, laravel-snappy

I am using laravel sail and I have an error when I use wkhtml to load PDF from blade files, I have installed the packages via composer and setup everything by following laravel-snappy instructions, the error goes as follows:

> The exit status code '255' says something went wrong: stderr:
> "qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such
> file or directory " stdout: "" command:
> /var/www/html/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
> --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy6231edb8e51c27.34391838.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy6231edb8e55b58.03612464.pdf'.

I am using M1 macbook air.